# use vendor function in exported es6 function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

How can I use a vendor javascript file inside an exported function?

Here is an example

main.js:

```
import myfunction from "./myfunctions/myfunction";

my function();
```

myfunction.js:

```
export default function myfunction() {
  // do something and want to call a function from a vendor file
}
```

files hierarchy:

```
main.js
myfunctions/myfunction.js
vendor/color-thief.js
```

Comment: just `import colorThief from 'vendor/color-thief'`in your `myfunction.js` file. Of course you have to figure the correct path, I assume you have a `base_path` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since at the time being `ColorThief` library does not use `module.exports` or similar (see https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/issues/85) you should import the script on your html and use the global variable exposed by the lib `window.ColorThief`.

```js
console.log(window.ColorThief)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.0.1/color-thief.min.js"></script>
```